# How to set up CKAN in RHEL

Tags: solr, ckan

I was following the steps given [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) to install CKAN from source in my Redhat Enterprise Linux 6 system.

At the [step 6](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#create-database-tables), I get the following output:

```
> (default)[hrishi@rd ~]$ cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
(default)[hrishi@rd ckan]$ paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
2015-05-15 11:23:35,695 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
    conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
    return self.select(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
    xml = self.raw(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
    rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
    return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
    raise ex
SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
2015-05-15 11:23:35,697 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
2015-05-15 11:23:35,927 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
    conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
    return self.select(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
    xml = self.raw(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
    rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
    return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
    raise ex
SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
2015-05-15 11:23:35,928 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
Initialising DB: SUCCESS
```

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Also, I followed [these steps](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production) to setup Solr in my system.

Comment: Can you access the Solr instance via browser?

Comment: @HendrikBunke yes. entering the IP with port as 8983 opens the Solr homepage.

Answer (score 0):

(just a wild guess) A common pitfall on RHEL systems is that the default SELinux configuration might not allow internal http connections. So try

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

(or simply disable SELinux).

And, of course, check your config ini if you really have the correct address and port of the Solr server. ;-)